# Priority of case versus default in golang select statements

Tags: go

I have an application with multiple goroutines that are running `for` loops, and need a way to signal these `for` loops to break, and to test whether the timeout case occurred. I was looking into using a shared channel with `select` statements to accomplish this as follows:

```
// elsewhere in the code, this channel is created, and passed below
done := make(chan struct{})
time.AfterFunc(timeout, func() { close(done) })
...
go func() {
Loop:
  for {
    select {
    case <-done:
      break Loop
    default:
      foo()
      time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
  }
  select {
  case <-done:
    panic("timed out!")
  default:
    // ok
  }
}()
```

Is this a valid way to accomplish this? What I'm most concerned about is that the branch of a `select` that is chosen could be non-deterministic, so that `default` may be chosen even if one of the `case`s is ready. Is this possible? Is there any documentation that states that a matching `case` is guaranteed to have preference over a `default`. The concern is that the for loop above could loop several times after `done` is closed and/or report success even though a timeout occurred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Select statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements)
>
> Execution of a "select" statement proceeds in several steps:
>
> 1. For all the cases in the statement, the channel operands of receive operations and the channel and right-hand-side expressions of send
>      statements are evaluated exactly once, in source order, upon entering
>      the "select" statement. The result is a set of channels to receive
>      from or send to, and the corresponding values to send. Any side
>      effects in that evaluation will occur irrespective of which (if any)
>      communication operation is selected to proceed. Expressions on the
>      left-hand side of a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or
>      assignment are not yet evaluated.
> 2. If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection.
>      Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen. If there
>      is no default case, the "select" statement blocks until at least one
>      of the communications can proceed.
> 3. Unless the selected case is the default case, the respective communication operation is executed.
> 4. If the selected case is a RecvStmt with a short variable declaration or an assignment, the left-hand side expressions are
>      evaluated and the received value (or values) are assigned.
> 5. The statement list of the selected case is executed.

---

> "What I'm most concerned about is that the branch of a select that is
>   chosen could be non-deterministic, so that default may be chosen even
>   if one of the cases is ready. Is this possible?"

No. See step 2 of the `select` specification.

Comment: This is also covered (in less detail) [in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/6).